# Why is my water heater still running if I cut the main line due to water problem located in my house

Tags: water

I had to cut off my main line, but why is the water heater still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's a tank-style heater: The tank leaks heat, and eventually gets cool enough that the thermostat switches the heat on. If you don't want that happening you'll need to explicitly turn off the heater.

Comment: In other words it is safe to go to sleep!!! I'm jus being paranoid

Comment: Yes. Unless there is something you haven't told us, this is normal and harmless.

Comment: But you probably SHOULD shut off the water heater. If there's no intake water, you can't really use it (no water pressure) so you're just wasting energy.

Comment: There's no problem leaving the heater running IF it is full of water (which is probably the case). On the other hand, if the problem with the plumbing has caused it to be partially drained, it MUST be switched off.

Comment: Switching it off until needed will also save some energy, of course. At least this isn't happening at midwinter, so there's no increased risk of frozen pipes